# Failed to start Raise network interfaces after Nginx SSL configuration

Tags: debian, networking, nginx

My networking service has failed to restart, first after some configuration, then after a reboot. I'd like to know why and how to resolve the issue.

As I'm fairly new to Linux, especially when it comes to complex configuration, I'll try to explain what I did to get so stuck. I have a virtual machine running Debian 9. On it, I installed Nginx in an attempt to run Gunicorn and Flask for a Python web app. I managed to set up a simple server and install SSL Certificates. Even Gunicorn worked on a subdomain. But the certificates, which were automatically installed and configured by Certbot, didn't include this subdomain. So I deleted the certificate, configured the server back to allow for another certificate install, this time a `certonly` one - I figured I'd gotten the configuration right. The certificate was installed, but approximately at that time my server stopped responding completely, as if it's blocking all traffic.

Trying a number of configurations ranging from my full subdomain conf to a minimalist default configuration, all of them pass `nginx -t` and restart fine, `ufw` allows all the correct ports, namely 80, 443 and 2222, which I use for ssh. However, `curl my_machine.net` refuses connections and `nmap` displays only the ssh port.

Below is the log of `journalctl -xe`, should that provide any information. Where could I begin debugging? I'm pretty sure it was either Nginx, Certbot or some other event not triggered by me (at least intentionally) that started this. `systemctl --all` shows no other services have failed, though some have their condition failed, which seems like a normal situation.

```
-- Unit networking.service has begun starting up.
Jul 08 18:33:13 my_machine.net ifup[989]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jul 08 18:33:13 my_machine.net ifup[989]: ifup: failed to bring up eth0
Jul 08 18:33:13 my_machine.net systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 08 18:33:13 my_machine.net systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit networking.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jul 08 18:33:13 my_machine.net systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 08 18:33:13 my_machine.net systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 08 18:33:13 my_machine.net sudo[982]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 08 18:33:21 my_machine.net kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=long_address SRC=short_address
Jul 08 18:33:26 my_machine.net sudo[1007]:    my_user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/my_user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -
Jul 08 18:33:26 my_machine.net sudo[1007]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by my_user(uid=0)
```

---

#### Adventures

- After a `dhclient -r` and another reboot, a different error is shown: `RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied`.
- [`/etc/sysctl.conf`](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/68190/how-do-i-resolve-rtnetlink-permission-denied-error-encountered-while-running-stacksh/) displays `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1`, but before editing such a file I'd like to make sure what exact effect this has on the system
- I do have general internet connection, apparent from ssh and curling outwards, e.g. `google.com`
- For what it's worth, `ping my_machine.net` works, but I guess that ought to
- The output of `ip route` is: `default via xx.xx.xx.1 dev eth0 onlink` `xx.xx.xx.0/24 via xx.xx.xx.1 dev eth0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, so. I did a reinstall and reconfiguration. All was well until I started adding subdomains again. A similar problem of not listening presented itself. This time `networking` was ok though.

It turns out symbolic linking sites from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled` with `ln -s` requires full, absolute paths. I was using relative ones. So no sites were included. While not a fix to the dhclient/ifup problem, it did resolve the issue for me.